# how to submit php post data with jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a form with action attribute as searchbycat.php. in the form there is a selection field based upon which contents in the php page will be dynamically made. so I am passing the selected value by GET and processing the value in searchbycat.php. so I am implementing jQuery's click event when the user clicks the submit button and changing the action attribute value with the selected value from the drop down menu. but it does not seem to work. I searched for this in stackoverflow and found that it can be done in jquery ajax call. but those answers is not really helping me. can somebody please explain how to do this?

here is my code:

```
<form action="" id="form1" method="POST">
        <select name="category">
            <option>Search By Category</option>
            <option value="mobile">Mobile Phone</option>
            <option value="computer">Computer Electronics</option>
            <option value="book">Books</option>
            <option value="fashion">Fashion and Beauty</option>
            <option value="furniture">Furniture</option>
            <option value="house">House Rent</option>
            <option value="vehicle">Vehicle</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="search" value="Search"/>
    </form>
```

and here is the Jquery part I am trying to do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').click(function(){
        $('#form1').attr("action","searchbycat.php?category=<?php echo $_POST['category']?>");
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry did not get you sir. jQuery attr function takes the attribute name as one of it's parameter so I did that in $('#form1').attr("action","searchbycat.php?category=<?php echo $_POST['category']?>");

Comment: Have you followed a [basic AJAX tutorial](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)?

Comment: no sir. no knowledge about ajax

Comment: Try This code ` $('#form1').attr("action","searchbycat.php?category=<?php echo $_POST['category']?>").submit();`

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't think his intention is to use ajax, merely to set the `category` parameter  of the get request using jQuery. Which is madness as he could just set the form action to `searchbycat.php` and change the method to `GET`. Job done

Comment: The title of the post leads me in the AJAX direction @Andrew, otherwise jQuery would be unnecessary, just as you say.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes, I can see why you'd think that

Comment: @andrew thanks for pointing out the simple solution. my head got stuck so bad that I did not even think about it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your form to method = 'GET' and action="searchbycat.php"
It will send automatically like you want. You don't really will need the jquery in this situation